# Should I use any or leave the type empty?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and it's going pretty well so far, but I'm missing the purpose of `any`.

Let's say I've got this block of code:

```js
const handleFoo = (foo: any, bar: object) => { /* magic happens here */ }
```

what is the difference between that block of code and the one below?

```js
const handleFoo = (foo, bar: object) => { /* magic happens here */ }
```

I can understand using `any` everywhere can cause a lot of clutter in your code. Should I use `any` when I have no specific type? Or should I just leave it empty..?

Comment: Probably best to type things properly and safely, but `any` isn't type-safe. If you really have no idea at all what the first argument will be, probably type it as `unknown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use typescript - the best thing is to define its type, `any` is dirty hack, because it leads us to issues that typescript tries to solve, when we can access wrongly typed variables / properties.

If you don't know the type (it can be anything), consider usage of `unknown` or `generics`.

```js
const handleFoo = (foo: unknown, bar: object) => {
  // now you need to check its type to access data like foo.test
  // when any allows it without type guard.
}

const handleFoo = <T>(foo: T, bar: object) => {
  // now foo is a kind of any, but with generic you have dynamic pointer
  // to its original type and foo.test also will show an error
  // until you solve it.
}

const handleFoo = <T extends {test: string}>(foo: T, bar: object) => {
  // like that for example
}
```